# Install PHP 5.3 after removing PHP 5.4 - libcurl.so.3()(64bit) issue

Tags: php, libcurl, centos6

I upgraded to PHP 5.4 and this caused issues with multiple of my scripts that use the deprecated mysql_connect function. I will need to redo these later in order to use it, but for now I would like to go back to PHP 5.3

I removed PHP 5.4 completely, added the webtactic repo, told the atomic repo to ignore php, php-*

I then do yum install php php-cli php-gd php-mysql php-mbstring and this happens:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink
 * atomic: www4.atomicorp.com
 * base: mirror.beyondhosting.net
 * epel: archive.linux.duke.edu
 * extras: centos.mbni.med.umich.edu
 * updates: centos.mbni.med.umich.edu
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.3.28-2.w5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.28-2.w5 for package: php-5.3.28-2.w5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.6()(64bit) for package: php-5.3.28-2.w5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.6()(64bit) for package: php-5.3.28-2.w5.x86_64
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.3.28-2.w5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libtermcap.so.2()(64bit) for package: php-cli-5.3.28-2.w5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libreadline.so.5()(64bit) for package: php-cli-5.3.28-2.w5.x86_64
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.3.28-2.w5 will be installed
---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.3.28-2.w5 will be installed
---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.3.28-2.w5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-pdo = 5.3.28-2.w5 for package: php-mysql-5.3.28-2.w5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) for package: php-mysql-5.3.28-2.w5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) for package: php-mysql-5.3.28-2.w5.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package compat-libtermcap.x86_64 0:2.0.8-49.el6 will be installed
---> Package compat-readline5.x86_64 0:5.2-17.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libmysqlclient15.x86_64 0:5.0.95-5.w5 will be installed
---> Package openssl098e.x86_64 0:0.9.8e-17.el6.centos.2 will be installed
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.28-2.w5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.3()(64bit) for package: php-common-5.3.28-2.w5.x86_64
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.3.28-2.w5 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-common-5.3.28-2.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)
           Requires: libcurl.so.3()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How do I resolve the libcurl.so.3()(64bit) issue?

Comment: `mysql_connect()` is not deprecated (note: 'deprecated' does _not_ mean 'removed') until PHP5.5, and at present it looks like support will continue with PHP5.6 as well. Whatever your problem was, a deprecated function wasn't the cause.

Comment: Understood, apologies for the wrong word usage. Alexandru G.'s response below resolved my issue of going back to PHP 5.3.3. As for what the problem with PHP 5.4 was, I don't have the error message anymore that I was getting. I'll be working on this in a test environment soon and will post an update once I begin to tackle that  issue. Thanks for the comment though =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered something similar a while back, when I accidentally installed an el5 repo on a el6 machine.

To fix the problem, I:

- removed all el5 installed packages. (I found them with `rpm -qa | grep el5`)
- removed el5 repo
- installed el6 repo

And after that all worked.

Seeing that "w5" tag in packages names, makes me think that you did a similar mistake and you installed a repository for centos 5 on a centos 6 machine.

Update: It looks like I was right. Webtatic it uses "[w5](http://us-east.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el5/SRPMS/)" tag for el5 packages and "[w6](http://us-east.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/SRPMS/)" tag for el6 packages. So you had an el5 repo installed on a el6 machine.

Comment: The only el5 package I had installed was htop-1.0.2-1.el5.rf.x86_64

I removed it, checked for any enabled el5 repos, there was rpmforge el5, disabled it. Still getting the same error

Edit: oops didn't install a el6 one though of rpmforge, guess I'll try that - gimme a min

Comment: I enabled the el6 rpmforge repo, still had the same error. I then disabled the webtatic repo and it worked!! Installed PHP 5.3.3 successfully. Thanks for the help!